# C#: Parsing through the HTML anchor tag

Tags: c#, html, xml, string, parsing

I have an anchor tag stored within a string:

```
<a class="yes" href="Folder/Default.aspx?use=abc&amp;employee=xxx1&amp;status=yes">XYZ</a>
```

I need to parse this string to find the value of the href attribute and the display text. Please advice.

P.S. Tried converting loading string into XML, however it throws exception -  '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'
Another way would be to use substring method, but I am looking for other alternatives.

Comment: do a google search on the following for starters `Decoding Anchor Tag in String`

Comment: Since HTML isn't necessarily correct XML, you may want to try a library like the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to decode the HTML for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a regex like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y9a0eQ):

```
string link = "<a class=\"yes\" href=\"Folder/Default.aspx?use=abc&amp;employee=xxx1&amp;status=yes\">XYZ</a>";
var href = Regex.Match(link, "href=\"(?<link>.*)\"").Groups["link"];
var display = Regex.Match(link, ">(?<display>.*)<").Groups["display"];
if (href.Success && display.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(href.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(display.Value);
}
```

But if you want to do real HTML parsing then you're better off using something like [HTMLAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
string link = "<a class=\"yes\" href=\"Folder/Default.aspx?use=abc&amp;employee=xxx1&amp;status=yes\">XYZ</a>";
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(link);
if (!document.ParseErrors.Any())
{
    var linkTarget = document.DocumentNode.FirstChild.Attributes["href"];
    var linkInnerText = document.DocumentNode.FirstChild.InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine("Link target: {0} Link text: {1}", linkTarget, linkInnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
string anchor = @"<a class=""yes"" href=""Folder/Default.aspx?use=abc&amp;employee=xxx1&amp;status=yes"">XYZ</a>";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(anchor);
string hrefvalue = xml.FirstChild.Attributes["href"].Value; // variable hrefvalue contains the value of the href attribute.
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).

Ex:

```
string html = "<a class=\"yes\" href=\"Folder / Default.aspx ? use = abc & amp;employee = xxx1 & amp;status = yes\">XYZ</a>";
string href = new CsQuery.CQ(html).Attr("href");
```

Comment: Recommending a library is off-topic in SO.

Comment: @FarhanAnam It isn't off-topic. Saving people time and effort instead of re-inventing a wheel is efficient programming.

Comment: @ChuckSavage I went about having the same theory. But in one of my questions I was told that it is off-topic by some guy who had >20k reputation. At first I thought that it was good to recommend a library and that he was talking rubbish but then I saw his profile and he was well reputed and had answered hundreds of questions and so... BTW, I am not the downvoter.